# SQL Server 2005: primary key columns and table columns - do they have to be in the same order?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, database-design, primary-key

A concept check:

from what I understand, the order of columns in a primary key (which is essentially a clustered index) should be decided based on the level of distinctness [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191195%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx))

But I did not see any explicit mention of the correlation between the order of columns in the *actual table* and the *primary key*.

Or put it in the other way, if the optimal order of columns in PK is `(B, C, A)`, will there be any performance impact if the table has the columns ordered as A, B, C (i.e. different from the PK definition)?

```
create table ABC (
A int,
B varchar(10),
C int)
```

My experience with SQL Server 2005 seems to indicate it does not matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "order" of columns in a table are an artifact of the way tables are defined - one of the key concepts of relational databases is that columns are located by name, not by ordinal position.

The actual layout of the columns in the database may not match the order that you've given - for instance, if you have multiple bit columns defined on the table, each set of eight will be packed into a single byte, no matter where they appear in the table definition.

For another example, all fixed length columns are packed at the start of the row. So in your example `ABC` table, the order of the columns in each row on disk would actually be `A`, `C`, `B` (but with some additional structures also appearing before column `A`, and between `C` and `B`.

In short, no, the order of columns in the table should not have any impact.

---

You can also find plenty of [examples of questions on SO](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3astackoverflow.com%20insert%20new%20column%20sql%20server%20position) where people are asking for ways to insert a column at a particular position within the table, and given similar answers - it should not matter where the column appears in the table definition - all that matters is where the column appears in select lists and, as you've mentioned, within index definitions.

---

You should also not conflate primary key and clustered index - the two do not have to be tied together. It's just the default behaviour that the primary key will become the clustered index on the table, if there isn't already a clustered index defined.

Comment: I think so too, but I cannot find any official documentation that supports this point. Do you know of any official source that covers this topic? Just want to convince my colleague...

Comment: @Anthony - for the examples of where the column order on disk don't match the table definition, I got most of my knowledge from "Inside SQL Server 2005: The Storage Engine" by Kalen Delaney - It's published by MS Press. I'm not aware of an online resource for the same info.

Comment: @Anthony - You can see this for yourself using [SQL Internals Viewer](http://internalsviewer.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 3):

A primary key is a *set* of attributes. In principle there is no order to the attributes of a key. Unfortunately SQL Server uses the order in which column names are specified in the key creation syntax to determine the order of columns in the index that supports that key. So you have to think about the specified ordering in just the same way as you consider the order of columns in an index.

A primary key is not the same thing as a clustered index. SQL Server requires an index to support key constraints but you can specify that the index is either clustered or nonclustered.

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter and makes no sense (different order)